# MYSQL Letters before numbers descending

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to get letters before numbers with a descending order and am finding it very difficult to do so.

I have tried using Case ordering

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ' . $this->sortbycast . ' LIKE \'%[a-z]%\' THEN 0 WHEN ' . $this->sortbycast . ' LIKE \'%[0-9]%\' THEN 1 ELSE ' . $this->sortbycast . ' END DESC
```

Regular expression as follows

```
' ORDER BY ' . $this->sortbycast . ' REGEXP \'^[a-z]\', ' . $this->sortbycast . ' desc';
```

and CAST()

```
' ORDER BY CAST(' . $this->sortbycast . '  AS UNSIGNED), ' . $this->sortbycast;
```

But none of these have had the desired result. All work correctly with ascending order. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update due to Strawberry's response**

[DB Fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Q7kJ6aqcpAfRF36xVEoVb/0)

My present query looks like this - reformatted for legibility:

```
SELECT p.*
     , m.data
     , m.id author_id 
  FROM anchor_posts p
  JOIN anchor_post_meta m
    ON m.post = p.id
 WHERE p.category = 5  
   AND m.extend = 3 
 ORDER 
    BY CAST('anchor_post_meta.data'  AS UNSIGNED) -- NOTE: THIS IS A STRING !?!
     , m.data DESC
 LIMIT 12;
```

**The desired result**

The desired result would be to have items show in the following order:

```
data
==============
A Title
B Title
C Title
D Title
70000
60000
45000
30000
25000
12000
```

Please [see the following version](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Q7kJ6aqcpAfRF36xVEoVb/2) of the DB Fiddle to see more clearly.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I've added a DB Fiddle to the OP.

Comment: There were 3 points in my response. This addresses only one (or perhaps two) of them

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance but which point would you like me to clarify?

Comment: The desired result.

Comment: I have now added the desired results.